# Функция не возвращает значение

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция, которая по json получает ip-адрес клиента:

```
$(function() {
    //var parser = '//freegeoip.net/json/';
    var clientip = $.get('//jsonip.com/', function(r){ return r.ip; });
    console.log(clientip);
});
```

Если в теле функции писать `console.log(r.ip);` то в консоль действительно выводится IP-адрес клиента. А если я в теле функции хочу вернуть аргументу функции IP-адрес, то по итогам `console.log(clientip);` я получаю строку `Object {readyState: 1}`. А если привожу код к следующему виду:

```
$(function() {
    //var parser = '//freegeoip.net/json/';
    var clientip = function() {
        $.get('//jsonip.com/', function(r){ return r.ip; });
    };
    console.log(clientip());
});
```

То получаю в консоли `undefined`. Где у меня ошибка?

Comment: вы присваиваете переменной функцию а не возвращаемое значение. попробуйте использовать window.test = r.ip;

Comment: О, еще одного человека в поиске забанили! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Метод `$.get` выполняется асинхронно, как и многое в javascript, в итоге вы пытаетесь вывести `clientip` раньше чем выполняется функция обратного вызова в запросе (Он там ведь пока подключится, пока получит ответ от сервера ну и т.д.).

Во втором случае, ваша функция ничего не возвращает, по этому в консоль ничего и не пишется, а метод `$.get` отдельной жизнью там себе живет, по причине описанной выше.

Хотите где то получить данные из запроса и использовать их, используйте функции обратного вызова:

```
var clientip = function(callback) {
    $.get('//jsonip.com/', function(r){ if(typeof callback == 'function'){ callback(r.ip); });
};
clientip(function(ip){
    //делаем что то дальше
});
```